# Почему в Google Analytics обращения к целям видно только в режиме реального времени, но в общей статистике совсем нет никакой информации о целях?

Tags: javascript, html5, вёрстка, google-analytics

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-131797669-1"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-131797669-1');
</script>
```

Использую событие как тип цели, а именно клик по кнопке:

```
<button onclick="gtag('event', 'click_button_send_contacts', {'event_category' : 'forms'}); return true;">Отправить контакты</button>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В режиме реального времени видно, что цели достигаются, но в Конверсии/Цели или на главной странице информации о целях нет, подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Информация о целях сразу не обновляется. Согласно документации до 24 часов необходимо для обработки данных.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь буду знать. Александр, а не подскажите, если мне нужно установить цель - клик на кнопке, которая ведет на совсем другой сайт, то для этого я могу использовать тип цели - целевая страница, URL тогда нужно полностью указывать, начиная с http://? Или для этого нужно использовать тип цели - событие?

Comment: Нет, не можете. Цель не будет учитываться. Нужно делать js клик на кнопку.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр!